# what is the difference between extends and normal calling?

Tags: php, oop, class

What is the difference between two codes?

Extends;

```
<?php 
require_once 'example.class.php';
Class First extends Example
{}
?>
```

Normal calling;

```
<?php
require_once 'example.class.php';
Class First
{
    public $example;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->example = new Example();
    }
}
?>
```

I know some difference for example using protected pharase.
But this is not enough in my opinion.

Comment: This is a very basic OOP question. I'd reccommend studying the basics of classes and inheritance first

Comment: Think of it like `class SUV extends Car` (take all the properties of a car, and make your modifications from there) or `class SUV` (start from scratch and define what an SUV is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one, the object First will have the same properties/functions of Example class. Like:

```
class Example
{
    public function a()
    {
    }
}

class First extends Example
{
    public function b()
    {
    }
}
```

if you instance two objects $ex1, $ex2:

```
$ex1 = new Example();
$ex1->a(); // this is valid
$ex1->b(); // this is invalid because Example doesn't have "b" function

$ex2 = new First();
$ex2->a(); // this is valid
$ex2->b(); // this is valid too, because First inherits Example members + its own
```

on the second code, you're creating an instance of example so you must access that variable to be able to call Example method.

one better example:

```
class Person
{
    public $name;

    public function say($message) 
    { 
        echo $this->name . " says " . $message;
    }
}

class Teacher extends Person
{       
    public function say($message) 
    { 
        // note that Teacher has a name even this is not declared here.
        echo $this->name . " says " . $message; 
    }

    public function teach($what) 
    { 
        // note that Teacher has a name even this is not declared here.
        echo $this->name . " is teaching " . $what; 
    }
}
```

See the output:

```
$john = new Person();
$john->name = "John Doe";
$john->say("hello world!");
/* 
$john->teach("Portuguese"); // invalid, person doesn't teach anything.
*/ 


$chuck = new Teacher();
$chuck->name = "Chuck Norris";
$chuck->say("hello universe!");
$chuck->teach("Fighting"); // valid because Teacher has method "teach"
```

Comment: shortly if i want to reach function b and function a i need to call example class or first class..?

Comment: Wow awesome that we got time to post responses :(

Comment: @MikePurcell We're here for this :)

Answer (score 1):

**Extends**

This is object inheritance. *First* inherits *Example* members, so *First* **is** *Example*.

An instance of *First* can call a method of *Example* and one of itself.

**Creating an instance of Example**

This just creating an object of *Example*. *First* methods *can* use other objects in order to achieve its goals.

---

I believe you need to get more in touch with object-oriented programming in order to learn more about its concepts and you'll understand things like this.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `First` extends `Example` so it has all its methods and properties.

In your second example you are just setting a property to be an object of the class `Example`. At least I assume that is what you want to do because the way you wrote it, `$example` is only defined in the scope of the constructor so it is never available anywhere.

I assume that for your second example you would want something like:

```
Class First
{
    protected $example;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->example = new Example();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jeroen is correct, but it also determines which attributes of the Example class can be accessed from the First class. For example, if the Example class has 2 methods which are private or protected, and you don't extend, the First class will not be able to access them.

Consider the following:

```
class Example
{
    public $foo;
    protected $bar;
}

Class First extends Example
{
    public function __construct()
    {            
        $this->foo = 'FOO1'; // Works because public scope
        $this->bar = 'BAR1'; // Works even though scope is protected, because we extended the class
    }
}

Class Second
{
    public example;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->example = new Example();

        $this->example->foo = 'FOO1'; // Works because public scope
        $this->example->bar = 'BAR2'; // Fails because protected scope and we did not extend the class
    }
}

// However, from the calling code, I am also limited
$first = new First();

$first->foo = 'NEW_FOO1'; // Works because public scope
$first->bar = 'NEW_BAR1'; // Fails because protected scope

$second = new Second();

$second->example->foo = 'NEW_FOO2'; // Works because public scope
$second->example->bar = 'NEW_BAR2'; // Fails because protected scope
```